# combinatorial proof of $2^{n+1}\nmid (n+1)(n+2)\dots (2n)$

Tags: combinatorics

combinatorial proof of $2^{n+1}\nmid (n+1)(n+2)\dots (2n)$.

I don't have any ideas about proving $sth \nmid sthx$ using combinatorics for showing $sth \mid sthx$ we show that there is a problem that gives $\frac{sthx}{sth*k}$ but what about proving sth doesn't divide sth using combinatorics?

Comment: A good starting point might be to count how many multiples of $2$ there are between $n+1$ and $2n$... and then how many multiples of $4$ there are... and then multiples of $8$, $16$, etc....

Comment: @LeeMosher I need a combinatorial proof not one using number theory.

Comment: That's not so much number theory as just common sense. There's still plenty of room for combinatorics ideas if you know how to make those counts. I would hope one is not forbidden to mix some common sense in with the combinatorics.

Comment: One technique would be to find a way to partition a set with $(n+1)\cdots(2n) $ into subsets that are *mostly* of sizes divisible by $2^{n+1}$, but with a few strays. Another way would be to find a way to partition them into subsets of size $2^n$ and show that there are an odd number of partition elements.

Comment: The intersection of combinatorics and number theory is definitely not empty.

Comment: But a "combinatorial proof" of an identity (or rule in this case) has a usual meaning - it starts with a set of a known size, and proves something about the size of that set by partitioning it, or creating a one-to-one correspondence with another set, or the like. It is a counting of set elements. @drhab

Comment: @ThomasAndrews could you explain more as an answer?

Comment: I haven't found a combinatorial proof yet, was just suggesting what a combinatorial proof of $2^{n+1}\not\mid Z$ would likely look like. @TahaAkbari

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $$p_n:=(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)$$ then $$p_{n+1}=p_n(2n+1)2$$ so it has exactly one factor $2$ more than $p_n$

Comment: Not a combinatorial proof.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is not a proof, but a hint. Is it really unthinkable that this inspires to a combinatorial proof? I will delete if the OP makes clear that it does not.

Comment: @drhab could you explain more please?

Comment: I have no combinatorial proof (yet). This answer provides a simple way to prove the statement by means of induction. If $2^n$ divides $p_n$ and $2^{n+1}$ does not then my answer shows that $2^{n+1}$ divides $p_{n+1}$ and $2^{n+2}$ does not.

Answer (score 0):

You want to establish that the highest possible power of 2 in the prime factorisation of (n+1)...(2n) is $2^n$.

On the left hand side you have n consecutive factors from n+1 to 2n. How many even numbers are there is these n factors ? There must be n/2 - so there is at least a factor of $2^{n/2}$ in the prime factorisation of (n+1)...(2n).

Now how many multiples of 4 are there from n+1 to 2n ? Well it depends on n, but let's take a "worst case" scenario - what is the maximum number of multiples of 4 from n+1 to 2n ? Each multiple of 4 increases the power of 2 in the prime factorisation of (n+1)...(2n) by 1.

Now carry on looking at multiples of 8, 16, 32 etc. The index of 2 increase each time, but by smaller and smaller amounts. Eventually you will reach a point where there are no more powers of 2 from n+1 to 2n - but, again, take a worst case scenario and assume n is really really large.

Can you see why the index of 2 in the prime factorisation of (n+1)...(2n) can never exceed n ?

Comment: There must be $n$ even numbers from $n+1$ to $2n$? There are only $n$ numbers from $n+1$ to $2n$.

Comment: @Thoma Andrews Oops. Thanks for pointing that out - I have fixed my post.

Comment: Except $n/2$ might not be an integer, of course, so you have to take care...